# Localization support in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-localizations

In my Flutter application, I have added support for English, Arabic, and Chinese languages. I am showing these three text widgets inside a List View. I would like to display Arabic language text only in RTL mode(Without Directionality widget). Any suggestions on this?

**Actual output:**

[image: Actual output]

**Expected output**

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code that would give other users a better idea of your widget and what would best work for your situation?

Comment: Hi @Jared,

In my case, I would like to apply localization to particular widgets only, not the entire app. There is any possible way for that?

Answer (score 3):

You can make the `text` widget position fixed either by wrapping it with `Align` widget

```
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: Text(
            'عربى',
          ),
        ),
```

Or change the `textAlign` property

```
        Text(
          'عربى',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
```

Comment: In my case, I would like to apply localization to particular widgets only, not the entire app. There is any possible way for that?

Comment: No, but you can exclude some widgets from the localization as shown in the example above.
basically by using default text and fixed alignment instead of directional alignment.